# Get Index value of a clicked DIV using JavaScript and hide all sibling matched with a higher Index number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am making a JavaScript library to mimic the Stacked Paper style that Basecam Project Management App uses.  See image below from my COdePen....

[image]

---

What I am trying to do is hide all Paper Divs that are stacked higher than the clicked on Paper.

So far I made a click event handler on the `.paper` class elements and I try to get the Index value of the clicked paper and then hide any paper Index numbers that are of higher value....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".paper", function(event) {
    alert('click on paper class');
    //event.preventDefault();
    var paperIndex = $(this).index(this);
    alert(paperIndex);

    $('.paper').filter(function(i) {
      console.log('i ===' + i);
      console.log('paperIndex ===' + paperIndex);
      return i > paperIndex;
    }).hide();
  });

});
```

---

This image below shows my Chrome Dev Tools Console output when I click on this `.paper`

[image]

[image]

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".paper", function(event) {
    alert('click on paper class');
    //event.preventDefault();
    var paperIndex = $(this).index(this);
    alert(paperIndex);

    $('.paper').filter(function(i) {
      console.log('i ===' + i);
      console.log('paperIndex ===' + paperIndex);
      return i > paperIndex;
    }).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
/* Mini Reset */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;             
}
body {background: #fff;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {margin: 0;}
h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}
h2 {font-size: 1.25em;}
h3 {font-size: 1.1em; text-transform: uppercase;}
a:link, a:visited {color: #000f55; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover, a:active {text-decoration: underline;}

/* Layout */

.paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto -50px;
    border: solid 1px #e9e9e9;
    min-height: 600px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
header, section {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
section{
  display: none;
}
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 200px; /* Number of Pages x 50px */
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.current {
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
}
.current section{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="project" class="paper">
    <a href="#">
      <header>
        <h1>WebDevApp Project</h1>
      </header>
      <section>
        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
          <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </a>
    <div id="task-lists" class="paper">
      <a href="#">
        <header>
          <h1>Task Lists on Project WebDevApp</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
          <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
          </ol>
        </section>
      </a>
      <div id="task-list" class="paper">
        <a href="#">
          <header>
            <h1>Task List WebDevApp UI/UX</h1>
          </header>
          <section>
            <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
            <ol>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
              <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
            </ol>
          </section>
        </a>
        <div id="task-details" class="current paper">
          <header>
            <h1>Task Details</h1>
          </header>
          <section>
            <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
            <img src="https://www.apollowebstudio.com/screenshots/2017/04/chrome_2017-04-13_18-25-07.png">
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- content -->
<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

---

### The Problem

No matter which `.paper` element I click on, it gives me an Index number of `0` for the `var paperIndex`.

What can I do to get the correct value or if there is a better way to accomplish my end goal that is good too.

Ultimately I need to convert it into native JavaScript as I was just using jQuery to get it working as a demo right now.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that version too but had no luck ill try again...actually that works with the index value but then it hides all of the DIVs for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).index(this)` doesn't make sense and would account for zero each time since you are indexing `this` in a collection that only contains itself

Probably want `$('.paper').index(this)`

Comment: actually that works with the index value but then it hides all of the DIVs for some reason

Comment: yeah I saw that, I should be able to use native JS and hide all descendants of clicked item with `.paper` class

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in your code:

1. index: jQuery `index` search for a given element from among the
   matched elements. So, the result of `$(this).index(this)` always
   return `0` because `$(this)` selected 1 element and the index of
   it-self must be 0.
2. even bubble up: You're adding event listener to all `.paper` elements which has a nested structure. When any event fire, it bubble up the event to the parent, that why your listener execute multiple times and only the root `.paper` shown.

How to fix:

1. index: You do not need to get the index anymore, just toggle children `.paper` of current element.
2. even bubble up: prevent it by using `event.stopPropagation()`

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.paper').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.paper {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="paper">
        Level 1.1

        <ul>
            <li class="paper">
                Level 1.1.1

                <ul>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.1.1</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.1.2</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.1.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="paper">
                Level 1.1.2

                <ul>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.2.1</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.2.2</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="paper">
                Level 1.1.3

                <ul>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.3.1</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.3.2</li>
                    <li class="paper">Level 1.1.3.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```